# Calculation of triangles side B if I know the angles and side a?

Tags: triangles, angle

How do I calculate the side B of the triangle if I know the following:

Side $A = 15 \rm {cm}
  ;\beta = 12^{\circ}
;\gamma= 90^{\circ}
;\alpha = 78^{\circ}
$

Thank you.

Comment: One of the angles is 90 degrees, so the triangle is a right triangle. What do you know about SOH, CAH, TOA?

Comment: @cws Note that if someone is from another country, SOH, CAH, TOA isn't necessarily a mnemonic they learn in school. I know I didn't. However, if you mention $\sin, \cos$ and $\tan$, they should probably understand regardless.

Answer (score 0):

For a $\triangle\text{ABC}$, we know that (for **EVERY** triangle):

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha^\circ+\angle\beta^\circ+\angle\gamma^\circ=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{\left|\text{A}\right|}{\sin\angle\alpha}=\frac{\left|\text{B}\right|}{\sin\angle\beta}=\frac{\left|\text{C}\right|}{\sin\angle\gamma}\\
\\
\left|\text{A}\right|^2=\left|\text{B}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{B}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

So, knowing your values:

$$
\begin{cases}
78^\circ+12^\circ+90^\circ=180^\circ\\
\\
\frac{15}{\sin\left(78^\circ\right)}=\frac{\left|\text{B}\right|}{\sin\left(12^\circ\right)}=\frac{\left|\text{C}\right|}{\sin\left(90^\circ\right)}\\
\\
15^2=\left|\text{B}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{B}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\left(78^\circ\right)\\
\\
\left|\text{B}\right|^2=15^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\cdot15\cdot\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\left(12^\circ\right)\\
\\
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=15^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\cdot15\cdot\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\left(90^\circ\right)
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So:

- $$\left|\text{B}\right|=\frac{15\cdot\sin\left(12^\circ\right)}{\sin\left(78^\circ\right)}\tag3$$
- $$\left|\text{C}\right|=\frac{15\cdot\sin\left(90^\circ\right)}{\sin\left(78^\circ\right)}=15\cdot\left\{2-\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{3\cdot\left(5-2\sqrt{5}\right)}\right\}\tag4$$

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{b}{a}$$ and so
$$b=\frac{a\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)}$$